# Not access background location on Android 10 and greater version

Tags: android, location, android-permissions, user-permissions, android-10.0

I am working on app having MinSdkVersion is 23 & TargetSdkVersion is 30 which requires background location for tracking the user. Below 10 it works fine but when it targeted to 10 & 11 background location is not access, I have to go manually to app info and from there I have to allow the location permission.Below is my code for getting permission.

```
  private void getPermission() {

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) +
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) +
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) +
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) + ActivityCompat
        .checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)

        + ActivityCompat


        .checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

{

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
            (LoginActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ||
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                    (LoginActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ||
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                    (LoginActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ||


            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                    (LoginActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ||


            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                    (LoginActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) ||


            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                    (LoginActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {

        Snackbar.make(LoginActivity.this.findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                "Please Grant Permissions to start using application",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE",
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            requestPermissions(
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                                            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                                    PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST);
                        }
                    }
                }).show();
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

On Manifiest file I mentioned below permisiions

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
```

From below image you can see that on verison below 10 it show the permission dialog to approve permission while on above it dont show permission dialog for approval
[image: Below 10 version permission dialog appears]

[image: Above 10 version permission dialog not appears]

Comment: Dont request the location permissions at the same time.

Comment: Reference: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/location#request-background-location-separately

Comment: @blackapps- It means I have to only use either background service or foreground service.So using this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />I dont want to use <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />